# Getting the current call stack from a different thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, callstack

In a multiple thread situation, is it possible to get the call stack at the current moment inside some thread `t1` from another thread `t2` running outside of `t1`? If so, how?

---

#### Response to Stefan:

I tried:

```
def a; b end
def b; c end
def c; d end
def d; sleep(1) end
t1 = Thread.new do
  100.times{a}
end
p t1.backtrace
```

but it always returns an empty array `[]`.

---

#### Edit:

Following suggestions by Stefan, the following parameters worked for my computer:

```
def a; b end
def b; c end
def c; d end
def d; end
t1 = Thread.new do
  1000.times{a}
end
sleep(0.0001)
p t1.backtrace
```

It returns a random call stack with the top-most method varying around `a` to `d`.

Comment: Like `t1.backtrace`?

Comment: @Stefan I don't know if you got my question as intended, but if I try as the code above, I always get the empty array, whereas I would expect some random call stack involving some from `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` method calls.

Comment: Maybe the thread already finished, try `def d; sleep; end`

Comment: @Stefan It is the same.

Comment: Seems like you have to wait a little (`sleep 0.1`) before calling `p t1.backtrace`

Comment: @Stefan That seems to be working. Please make that an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`Thread#backtrace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#method-i-backtrace) but apparently it takes some time for the thread to start:

```
def baz
  loop until @baz
end

def bar
  baz
  loop until @bar
end

def foo
  bar
  loop until @foo
end

t1 = Thread.new { foo }

sleep 0.1                # wait for the thread
p t1.backtrace

@baz = true; sleep 0.1   # exit 3rd method
p t1.backtrace

@bar = true; sleep 0.1   # exit 2nd method
p t1.backtrace

@foo = true; sleep 0.1   # exit 1st method
p t1.backtrace
```

Output:

```
["thread.rb:2:in `baz'", "thread.rb:6:in `bar'", "thread.rb:11:in `foo'", "thread.rb:15:in `block in <main>'"]
["thread.rb:7:in `bar'", "thread.rb:11:in `foo'", "thread.rb:15:in `block in <main>'"]
["thread.rb:12:in `foo'", "thread.rb:15:in `block in <main>'"]
nil
```